# How do I connect to PostgreSQL in Heroku without using Spring?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I m trying to deploy a simple CRUD app on Heroku. However I dont want to use Spring. What I m using is JSF ( Primefaces) and JPA (Hibernate) for persistence. When I m trying to connect to db I m getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The user must supply a JDBC connection
org.hibernate.connection.UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.getConnection(UserSuppliedConnectionProvider.java:54)
org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:60)
org.Handlers.UserHandler.getAllUsers(UserHandler.java:31)
org.tutorial.LoginBean.authenticate(LoginBean.java:52)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)
org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
```

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<persistence-unit name="test">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
  <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  <property name="url" value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + @dbUrl.getPath() }"/>
  <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }"/>
  <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }"/>
  <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
   <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
</properties>
```

I have copied the properties from the applicationcontext.xml file.

Anybody has an idea what might be the problem?? I have looked into similar posts but couldnt find the solution.

My pom.xml is the following:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
       <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
       <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <classifier/>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.4.Final</version>
        <classifier/>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
        <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.27.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>                       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also gone through the same problem as yours .The above configuration in persistence unit and pom.xml is correct but there might be mistake in applicationcontext.xml which u have not included here.

Following is the part of applictioncontext.xml where you might have flaw.

```
<bean class="java.net.URI" id="dbUrl">
        <constructor-arg value="#{systemEnvironment['DATABASE_URL']}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />       
        <property name="url" value="#{ 'jdbc:postgresql://' + @dbUrl.getHost() + @dbUrl.getPath() }" />
        <property name="username" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[0] }" />
        <property name="password" value="#{ @dbUrl.getUserInfo().split(':')[1] }" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="test"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />

                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

IF you need any help ,let me know.